# Playing audio files with libao

Tags: c, linux, audio, wav, aiff

I'm trying to make a simple C program play an AIFF or WAV file.  Based on what I see at http://www.xiph.org/ao/doc/, this should work, but instead it makes a buzzing sound no matter what file I feed it.  What's wrong with this?

```
/* compile with "gcc -o playme playme.c -lao -ldl -lm" */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ao/ao.h>
#include <math.h>

ao_device *device;
ao_sample_format format;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int default_driver;
    char *buffer;
    unsigned long count;

    FILE *fp;

    if (argc != 2) {
    printf("usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
    }

    ao_initialize();
    default_driver = ao_default_driver_id();
    memset(&format, 0, sizeof(format));

    format.bits = 16;
    format.channels = 2;
    format.rate = 44100;
    format.byte_format = AO_FMT_LITTLE;

    device = ao_open_live(default_driver, &format, NULL /* no options */);
    if (device == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening sound device.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open %s.\n", argv[1]);
    exit(2);
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    count = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), count, fp);
    ao_play(device, buffer, count);
    ao_close(device);
    ao_shutdown();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A critical something I didn't realize is that libao does absolutely no decoding.  It is therefore up to the programmer to extract the sample size, rate, channels, etc and feed those to libao before opening the audio device.  libsndfile is available for doing this, but if you just want something quick and dirty, here's the code for playing an AIFF file:

```
/* compile with "gcc -o playaiff playaiff.c -lao -ldl -lm" */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ao/ao.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAXCHAN 8

ao_device *device;
ao_sample_format format;

#define gshort( b) (((int)((b)[0]) << 8) + (int)((b)[1]))
#define glong( b) (((int)((b)[0]) << 24) + ((int)((b)[1]) << 16) +\
        ((int)((b)[2]) << 8) + (int)((b)[3]))

typedef struct {
    short     channels;
    short     samplesize;
    int   samplerate;
    unsigned long samplecount;
    int       valid;
} aiffinfo;

aiffinfo getaiffinfo(FILE *);
static int IeeeExtendedToLong(unsigned char *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int default_driver;
    char *buffer;

    aiffinfo info;

    FILE *fp;

    if (argc != 2) {
    printf("usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
    }

    ao_initialize();
    default_driver = ao_default_driver_id();
    memset(&format, 0, sizeof(format));

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open %s.\n", argv[1]);
    exit(2);
    }

    info = getaiffinfo(fp);

    if (!info.valid) {
    printf("Invalid AIFF file.\n");
    exit(1);
    }

    format.bits = info.samplesize;
    format.channels = info.channels;
    format.rate = info.samplerate;
    format.byte_format = AO_FMT_LITTLE;

    device = ao_open_live(default_driver, &format, NULL /* no options */);
    if (device == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening sound device.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * info.samplecount);

    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), info.samplecount, fp);
    ao_play(device, buffer, info.samplecount);
    ao_close(device);
    ao_shutdown();

    return 0;
}


aiffinfo getaiffinfo(FILE *fp)
{
    int size;
    int len;
    int offset;
    int blocksize;
    int found = 0;
    unsigned char chunk[18];
    unsigned char fid[4];
    aiffinfo info;

    info.samplesize = 0;
    info.valid = 0;

    if (fread(chunk, 1, 4, fp) < 4) return info;
    if (memcmp(chunk,"FORM",4)) return info;
    if (fread(chunk, 1, 4, fp) < 4)  return info;
    size = glong(chunk);
    if (size & 1) size++;
    if (size < 20) return info;
    if (fread(chunk, 1, 4, fp) < 4) return info;
    if (memcmp(chunk, "AIFF", 4)) return info;

    size -= 4;
    while (size > 8) {
    if (fread(fid, 1, 4, fp) < 4) return info;    // chunck id
    if (fread(chunk, 1, 4, fp) < 4) return info;    // and len
    size -= 8;
    len = glong(chunk);
    if (len < 0) return info;
    if (len & 1) len++;
    size -= len;
    if (size < 0) return info;
    if (memcmp(fid, "COMM", 4) == 0) {
        if (len != 18) return info;
        if (fread(chunk, 1, 18, fp) < 18) return info;
        info.channels = gshort(chunk);
        if (info.channels < 1) return info;
        if (info.channels > MAXCHAN) return info;
        info.samplecount = glong(chunk+2);
        if (info.samplecount < 1) return info;
        info.samplerate = IeeeExtendedToLong(chunk + 8);
        if (info.samplerate <= 0) return info;
        info.samplesize = gshort(chunk + 6);
        if (info.samplesize < 1 || info.samplesize > 16) return info;
    } else if (memcmp(fid,"SSND",4)==0){
        if (!info.channels) return info;
        if (fread(chunk, 1, 4, fp) < 4) return info;
        offset = glong(chunk);
        if (fread(chunk, 1, 4, fp) < 4) return info;
        blocksize = glong(chunk);
        if (blocksize) return info;
        if (offset) fseek(fp, offset,SEEK_CUR);
        found = 1;
        break;
    } else fseek (fp, len, SEEK_CUR);
    }

    if (!found) return info;
    if (!info.channels) return info;

//    printf("Looks good so far.\n");
    info.valid = 1;
    return info;
}


/****************************************************************
 * Extended precision IEEE floating-point conversion routine.
 ****************************************************************/

#ifndef Uint32
#define Uint32 unsigned int
#endif
#ifndef HUGE_INT32
#define HUGE_INT32 0x7fffffff
#endif                                          /* HUGE_VAL */

static int IeeeExtendedToLong( unsigned char *bytes)
{
    int f = 0;
    int expon;
    Uint32 hiMant;
    Uint32 loMant;

    expon = ((bytes[0] & 0x7F) << 8) | (bytes[1] & 0xFF);
    hiMant = ((Uint32) (bytes[2] & 0xFF) << 24)
    | ((Uint32) (bytes[3] & 0xFF) << 16)
    | ((Uint32) (bytes[4] & 0xFF) << 8)
    | ((Uint32) (bytes[5] & 0xFF));
    loMant = ((Uint32) (bytes[6] & 0xFF) << 24)
    | ((Uint32) (bytes[7] & 0xFF) << 16)
    | ((Uint32) (bytes[8] & 0xFF) << 8)
    | ((Uint32) (bytes[9] & 0xFF));

    if (expon == 0 && hiMant == 0 && loMant == 0) f = 0;
    else if (expon == 0x7FFF) f = HUGE_INT32;
    else {
    expon -= 16382;
    expon = 32-expon;
    if (expon < 0) f = HUGE_INT32;
    else f = hiMant >> expon;
    }

    if (bytes[0] & 0x80)
    return -f;
    else
    return f;
}
```